# Don't understand this tkinter.TclError

Tags: python, tkinter

I can't seem to set (update) the column which I previously created to a value from a function which is called when I click a button, it says Item not found.

```
curItem = tree.focus()
contents =(tree.item(curItem))
selecteditem = contents['values']
tree.get_children(curItem)
Database()
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(PRODUCT_QTY) FROM `product` WHERE `product_id` = %d" % selecteditem[0])
fetch = cursor.fetchall()
for data in fetch:
   # d = tree.item(data)
    tree.set(selecteditem, 3, data)
    a = data
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

The Error and traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",
     line 1705, in __call__ return self.func(*args)
File "c:\Users\.\Desktop\Simple_Inventory PYTHON\Simple Inventory System\index.py",
      line 268, in calculate tree.set(selecteditem, 2, data)
File "C:\Users\.\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py",
      line 1482, in set res = self.tk.call(self._w, "set", item, column, value)
      _tkinter.TclError: Item 8 e 3 4 not found
```

NOTE: 8 is the ID of the item, e the name,3 and 4 the price and quantity (dummy values)

Comment: Change to `selecteditem = curItem`

Comment: It actually worked thank you such a simple solution

Comment: I've moved your answer from your question into a community wiki.  Next time - don't add "Solved" to your question, and feel encouraged to post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `selecteditem` to some *values*. The argument to `tree.set` must be an *identifier*. Like the error says, there is nothing in the tree with an id of `8 e 3 4`.

The identifier will be whatever is returned when you called `tree.insert`. It will either be an indentifier computed for you of the form "IXXX" (eg: `I001`), or whatever you specified when you called `tree.insert`.

Since you didn't show how you created the items in the tree it's hard to say what the value should be. It might be enough to use `curItem`, but from the tiny bit of code you provided it's hard to say for certain.

Comment: The error still is the same if i use selecteditem[0] (the id column)

Comment: @Em44: it's not the database id. You need to give it the id that the treeview gave you when you created that row.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may struggle with the same problem, simply putting the `curItem` instead of `selectedItem[0]` in the `tree.set()` parameters fixes it.  Just put in the focused tree variable there.